# Why my pagination is not working?

Tags: php, pagination

So I was trying to do pagination with php, but I can't quite get it done, there is an error of undefined index page in it somewhere, I have no idea why...here is my code:

```
        <?php
            $perpage = 10;

            if (empty($_GET['page'])) {
                $page = 1;
            }else{
                $page = $_GET['page'];
            }

            $limitstart = $_GET['page'] - 1 * $perpage;

            $query = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT '".$limitstart."', '".$perpage."' ";

            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));

            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>
```

I appreciate your help in any way, thank you.

Comment: `empty()` should be `isset()` instead. empty is a pretty much useless function and generally doesn't work as people would expect it to. `$foo = '0'; empty($foo)` evaluates to true, for instance

Comment: you don't need quotation for your limit values

Comment: It's not an error, it's a notice, which is *very* different. That has [already been answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4261133/938236).

Answer (score 3):

`$limitstart = $_GET['page'] - 1 * $perpage;`

is the same as (remember your math class)

`$limitstart = $_GET['page'] - (1 * $perpage);`

You would like to use

`$limitstart = ($page - 1) * $perpage;`

(also note the usage of your $page-variable)